# spring:message show message in multiple languages on the same page

Tags: spring, internationalization

I have this requirement from a client to build a landing page that welcomes users in both languages supported by the website.

My expectation was that i could do something like:

```
<spring:message code="code" locale="en"/>
```

Apparently this is not possible, so I was wondering if there was any support for this, or do I have to build my own controller to serve these messages with an extra locale parameter?

**i18n language support already works** what i am looking for, is a way to render, on the same page, the same message from multiple languages.

Imagine a landing page with two boxes,

- first one shows a big EN flag and welcome text (`messageCode="landing.welcome"`) in English.
- second one shows a big PT flag and welcome text (`messageCode="landing.welcome"`) in Portuguese.

**again: both these languages work with the client's locale (either PT or EN) but what i need is to get the same message code in both languages**

Comment: Have you setup the MessageSource?

Comment: I have the messageSource configured and use it everywhere in the app... that works fine. But what I want now is to display the same message code, in multiple languages, on the same page. So I wanted to specify the locale explicitly, hence overriding the client's locale from the LocaleResolver.

Comment: Have you tried suffixing a message source with the locale abbreviation?  So if your message source is `messages.properties` make a `messages_en.properties`

Comment: @KevinBowersox ???? I have multiple language support... I guess my question is not clear enough will try to update

Comment: My understanding is you need a message source for each locale

Comment: @KevinBowersox is it clearer now?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So what I am doing in the meantime to implement this is using a controller that has a reference to the message source and puts both messages into the model.

```
@Controller
public class LandingController {

    private static final String LANDING_CODE = "landing.welcome";
    @Autowired
    private MessageSource messageSource;

    @RequestMapping("/")
    public String render(Model model) {
        model.addAttribute("welcomeMessagePt", messageSource.getMessage(LANDING_CODE, null, new Locale("PT")));
        model.addAttribute("welcomeMessageEn", messageSource.getMessage(LANDING_CODE, null, Locale.ENGLISH));

        return "index";
    }
}
```

but i hoped the controller would not be needed...

Comment: Same problem. Any better solution?? Unfortunately i have too many messages in a page to differentiate in the controller.

Comment: @DonkeyKong Did you ever solve this with a better solution?